# Почему SQL не создает таблицу?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток, товарищи! Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.. Начал я учить СУБД MySQL, нашел литературу, все такое.. Но вот один пример не получается даже повторить. Вот он у меня перед глазами, а на машине не работает. Вот код:

```
-- Создание индекса при создании таблицы
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table5;
CREATE TABLE table5
(
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Код товара',
code CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAA' COMMENT 'Код товара',
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Название товара',
price FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Цена товара',
CONSTRAINT pkId PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT ixCode UNIQUE KEY (code),
INDEX ixName (name),
INDEX ixPrice (price)
```

) COMMENT 'Таблица товаров с ключем и индексами';

```
-- Создание таблицы с ВНЕШНИМ индексом
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table6_child;
CREATE TABLE table6_child
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Код записи',
code CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'AAAA' COMMENT 'Код товара',
quo FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Приход/расход товара',
CONSTRAINT pkId PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX ixCode (code),
CONSTRAINT fkTable5Code FOREIGN KEY (code)
    REFERENCES teble5 (code)
);
```

Не создает зверь заморский вторую таблицу! Выдает ответ в виде:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'modul3.table6_child' (errno: 150)
```

Движок InnoDB стоит, активен.. Тип данных в ключевой колонке, как видно, один и тот же.. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

teble5 может быть table5.

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Ошибки на невнимательность - самые противные, особенно, если язык новый.

P.S. Клёвый ник :)

Comment: Жмакни плюсик если помогло